# Algebraic model for the abelian category of descent data for modules in the non-affine case

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, descent

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a morphism of schemes. I'd like to have a completely algebraic description of the belian category of descent data for modules along $f$. Here's my attempt:

The category of quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_{X \times_Y X}$ modules caries a monoidal structure for which $\mathcal{O}_X$ is the unit (given by tensor product and pulling and pushing along obvious diagrams). Inside this category $\mathcal{O}_{X \times_Y X}$ has a canonical structure of a counital coalgebra over $\Delta_*\mathcal{O}_X$ with counit given by multiplication

$$\mathcal{O}_{X \times_Y X} \to \Delta_*\mathcal{O}_X$$

And comultiplication given by the insertion of the unit in the middle.

Denote by $LCoMod(\mathcal{O}_{X \times_Y X})$ the category of left quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_{X \times_Y X}$-comodules.

In the affine case this category is equivalently coalgebras over the comonad $f^*f_* \to Id$ which is the category of descent data by monadic descent.

> **Question:** Is $LCoMod(\mathcal{O}_{X \times_Y X})$ a model for the category of descent data in the non-affine case?

Comment: If $f$ is flat, this should be the case. Consider the description of quasi-coherent sheaves over a geometric stack by comodules over the associated Hopf algebroid, a category which is equivalent to the category of descent data.

Comment: @LeoAlonso sorry if this is stupid but this is something i'm having a problem with for some time now, what is Hopf Algebroid really? I mean a precise definition which agrees with the main bulk of the literature. By the way, my end goal is to derive everything to get a simple algebraic model for derived descent data so the flat part isn't terribly important probably.

Comment: Look at our paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.2520 where full details are given. If you are interested on the derived situation probably you want to look at Pridham's https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.4044 .